# Java : String to date conversion

Tags: java

How can i convert the following date string to `Date` in java. I am trying `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
Date parse = sdf.parse("2012-02-14T20:23:40.127");
```

it throws :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-02-14T20:23:40.127"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at Play.main(Play.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What pattern are you using to create the formatter?

Comment: Not going to work - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are (probably) using the wrong date format pattern. Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

---

Here's this code in action:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = sdf.parse("2012-02-14T20:23:40.127");
System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

```
Tue Feb 14 20:23:40 EST 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse(date_in).getTime());
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
            return date;
```

Where `date_in` is the date in String.

Comment: for `"2012-02-14T20:23:40.127"` `Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-02-14T20:23:40.127"`

Comment: You can refer to you date format that is `yyyy-MM-ss'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`.Try it

Answer (score 0):

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        try {
            Date parse = sdf.parse("2012-02-14T20:23:40.127");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Using the Joda-Time library, you can pass that string directly to the DateTime constructor, as Joda-Time uses such ISO 8601 formats by default.

## Time Zone

Pass a time zone by which to interpret that string, as the string lacks a time zone offset. If the string is UTC, pass the constant `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

## Example Code

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime ( "2012-02-14T20:23:40.127", timeZone);
```

If you need a java.util.Date object for use with other classes, convert from Joda-Time.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```